# angularjs data in service can not be share between different controller

Tags: angularjs, service

I create service :

```
.factory('patientListBarService', function() {
    var data = {
        pages: 0,
        total:0
    };
    return data;
})
```

my ctl 1:

```
.controller('patientCtl', ['$scope', '$http', 'patientListBarService', function($scope, $http, patientListBarService){
    console.log(patientListBarService);
    $scope.pages = patientListBarService.pages;
    $scope.total = patientListBarService.total;
    $scope.$watch('patientListBarService.pages', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        console.log('====pages:' + patientListBarService.pages);
        $scope.pages = patientListBarService.pages;
    });
    $scope.$watch('patientListBarService.total', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        console.log('====total:' + patientListBarService.total);
        $scope.total = patientListBarService.total;
    });
}]);
```

my ctl 2:

```
controller('patientListCtl', ['$scope', 'patients', '$http', 'patientListBarService', function($scope, patients, $http, patientListBarService){
    console.log("----patient list ctl----");
    console.log(patients);
    patientListBarService.pages = patients.config.pages;
    patientListBarService.total = patients.config.total;
}]);
```

the ctl1 run before ctl2.
after ctl2 run, ctl1's

```
$scope.pages
$scope.total
```

display the right value on my view.

however, their display not change after I run ctl2 more times.

I am new to ng...

Anyone help me?  thanks !!!

Comment: is that  ·patientListBarService.pages = patients.config.pages;·  'patientListBarService.total = patients.config.total;' change every time? otherwise the display wont be change

Comment: Yes,it changes everytime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your service data into an object, you don't need the watches and the values will be synced automatically

```
.controller("Test1", function($scope, Serv){
  $scope.serv = Serv.data;

  $scope.modify = function(){
    $scope.serv.param1 = Math.random()*100;
    $scope.serv.param2 = Math.random()*100;
  }
})

.controller("Test2", function($scope, Serv){
  $scope.serv = Serv.data;
})

.factory("Serv", function(){
  var data = {
    param1: '',
    param2: ''
  }

  return {
    data: data
  }
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qowixakura/1/edit?html,js,output)